# How to adapt this CSS for Chrome, IE, Safari?

Tags: html, css

I have CSS to make list items like staggered cards but it works only in Firefox browser, in another browser on large screens it shows an one column only instead two. How can I adapt it for Chrome, IE, Safari browsers?

```css
ul.page_card_grid {
 margin: 16px 0 16px 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

ul.page_card_grid li {
 display: block;
 clear: both;
}

ul.page_card_grid li a {
 display: block;
 color: #999;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 16px auto 16px auto;
 padding: 20px 16px 16px 16px;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

ul.page_card_grid li a p {
 margin: 8px 0 8px 0;
 color:#555;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
}

ul.page_card_grid li a img {
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

ul.page_card_grid li a:hover, ul.page_card_grid li a:focus, ul.page_card_grid li a:active {
 box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
 background-color: #eee;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {

 ul.page_card_grid {
  margin: 16px 0 16px 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
 }

 ul.page_card_grid > :nth-child(2n + 1) { 
  order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
 } /* 1st column */

 ul.page_card_grid > :nth-child(2n + 2) { 
  order: 2;
  -webkit-order: 2;
 } /* 2nd column */

 ul.page_card_grid > :nth-child(-n + 2) {
    page-break-before: always; /* CSS 2.1 syntax */
  -webkit-page-break-before: always;
    break-before: always;  /* New syntax */
  -webkit-break-before: always;
 }

 ul.page_card_grid li {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
 }

 ul.page_card_grid li a {
  display: block;
  -webkit-display: block;
  width: 240px;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 20px 16px 16px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
 }

 ul.page_card_grid li a:hover, ul.page_card_grid li a:focus, ul.page_card_grid li a:active {
  background-color: #fff;
 }
}
```

```html
<ul class="page_card_grid">
 <li>
  <a href="http://local/index.php/sample-page/and-one-yet/">
   <p>And one yet</p>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="http://local/index.php/sample-page/child-page-1/">
   <img width="96" height="96" src="http://local/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ic-1-150x150.png" class="attachment-96x96 size-96x96" alt="ic" srcset="http://local/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ic-1-150x150.png 150w, http://local/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ic-1.png 256w" sizes="(max-width: 96px) 100vw, 96px" />
   <p>Child page 1</p>
   Are you a student? Our app helps you to always know your schedule.
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="http://local/index.php/sample-page/child-page-2/">
   <p>Child page 2</p>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="http://local/index.php/sample-page/one-yet-page/">
   <p>One yet page</p>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `float: top` doesn't exist...

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I removed it. But my problem in another.

Comment: The problem appears to be unstable browser support for the `page-break-before` property. Works (as intended) in Firefox, but not in Chrome. http://caniuse.com/#search=page-break-before

Comment: And how can I fix it? Maybe it has a some another solution

Answer (score -1):

You can add following for every browser.

**For Chrome and Safari**

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

**For IE**

```
-ms-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

**For Opera**

```
-o-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

**For Mozila**

```
-moz-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I need to fix a columns count for these browsers on large screens, not highlighters.

Comment: add prefix -moz- , -o-, -ms etc in every css. Try it. You have mentioned that you have css that's why i listed this.

Comment: Hm, sorry, Imma not a web-developer, just I need to fix one page on my site. Can you post a sample?

Comment: Like you have added background-color: #fff; box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0;   rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); overflow:hidden; Change it to -o-background-color: #fff;
-o-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0; -o-overflow:hidden; for opera.

Comment: Sorry, but that's ridiculous. Only a very small set of CSS properties have or need vendor prefixes. `background-color` and `overflow` are certainly not among them.

Comment: @Pirate, I updated attributes of wrapping (see topic) for the WebKit support but it doesn't work.